# C++ program compilation error

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I was making a Texas Hold'em Poker game, the game isn't an actual simulation of a poker game so don't expect any betting and folding. It's purely point based, the thing is I made it in 2 days and didn't have time to "refine" it, and I didn't go the object oriented path. Know after clearing all the syntax based errors I face a compiler error that I can't understand. I tried everything to fix it but it seems I have no idea what it's about. So if someone can derive any meaning for the compiler's output please refer me to what i'm doing wrong.

FULLCODE:http://pastebin.com/njdAzmrB

COMPILER OUTPUT:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "HANDDISTRO(int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fullhouse1(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fullhouse2(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fullhouse3(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fullhouse4(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "ONDECKINDEX(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "RoyalFlush1(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "RoyalFlush2(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "RoyalFlush3(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "RoyalFlush4(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fourofkind1(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fourofkind2(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fourofkind3(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "fourofkind4(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "threeofkind1(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse1(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind1(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind2(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind3(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind4(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "threeofkind2(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse2(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "threeofkind3(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse3(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "threeofkind4(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse4(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "straightflush1(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "straightflush2(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "straightflush3(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "straightflush4(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "ONDECK(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "flush1(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush1(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "flush2(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush2(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "flush3(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush3(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "flush4(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush4(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "SHUFFLE(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "onepair1(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse1(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind1(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind2(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind3(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
      fourofkind4(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "onepair2(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse2(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "onepair3(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse3(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "onepair4(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      fullhouse4(int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "twopair1(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "twopair2(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "twopair3(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "twopair4(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
  "Straight1(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush1(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "Straight2(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush2(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "Straight3(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush3(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
  "Straight4(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in poker1-0374f4.o
      straightflush4(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int*, int*) in poker1-0374f4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

SOURCECODE:

```
int main(){
srand (time(NULL)); /* initialize random seed: */

int size1=5;
int size2=52;
int size3=2;
int score1, score2, score3, score4 = 0;
string winhand1, winhand2, winhand3, winhand4;

int hand1[size3];//hand or player1
string hand1index[2]; //index to monitor the suit
int hand2[size3];//hand or player2
string hand2index[2]; //index to monitor the suit
int hand3[size3];//hand or player3
string hand3index[2]; //index to monitor the suit
int hand4[size3];//hand or player4
string hand4index[2]; //index to monitor the suit
int deck[size2];//deck
string deckindex[52];//index to monitor the suit
int Ondeck[size1];//Cards on deck
string Ondeckindex[5]; //index to monitor the suit
int used[size2];//used index
string usedindex[52];//index to monitor the suit

/*
           All Card's SUITS AND RANKS COMBINED !!!
           INDEX WILL BE USED TO COMPARE SUITS !!!
           0 1 2 3
           h s c d
           e p l i
           a a u a
           r d b m
           t e s o
           s s ^ n
           ^ ^ | d
           | | | s
*///       | | | ^
int c2[4]={2,2,2,2};
int c3[4]={3,3,3,3};
int c4[4]={4,4,4,4};
int c5[4]={5,5,5,5};
int c6[4]={6,6,6,6};
int c7[4]={7,7,7,7};
int c8[4]={8,8,8,8};
int c9[4]={9,9,9,9};
int c10[4]={10,10,10,10};
int c11[4]={11,11,11,11}; //JACK
int c12[4]={12,12,12,12}; //QUEEN
int c13[4]={13,13,13,13}; //KING
int c14[4]={14,14,14,14}; //ACE

//HANDS
int RF[5] = {14, 13, 12, 11, 10}; //Royal Flush
//GAME BEGINS
while(true){
  label1:
  char choice;
  cout << "#######                                  #######" << endl;
  cout << "   #    ###### #    #    ###     #####   #     # ###### #   #  ###### ##### " << endl;
  cout << "   #    #       #  #    #   #   #        #     # #    # #  #   #      #    #" << endl;
  cout << "   #    #####    ##     # # #   ######   ####### #    # ###    ###### ##### " << endl;
  cout << "   #    #        ##     #   #        #   #       #    # #  #   #      #    #" << endl;
  cout << "   #    #       #  #    #   #        #   #       #    # #   #  #      #    #" << endl;
  cout << "   #    ###### #    #   #   #   #####    #       ###### #    # ###### #    #" << endl << endl;
  cout << " HELLO TO TEXAS HOLD'EM POKER!\n";
  cout << " Hello, this is a 4 player game\n";
  cout << " No betting is implemented in this game\n";
  cout << " Wining happens through a point driven system\n";
  cout << " So, the higher the hands the higher the points\n";
  cout << " HAVE FUN !!!\n";
  cout << " \n";
  cout << " \n";
  cout << " Press 's' or 'S' to start\n";
  cout << " OR\n";
  cout << " Press 'q' or 'Q' to quit\n";
  cin>>choice;
  if(choice=='q'||choice=='Q') EXIT_SUCCESS;
  else if(choice=='s'||choice=='S'){
    int count=0;
    cout << "Shuffling Cards...\n";
    cout << "This takes a while...\n";
    cout << "what do you think i'm a computer !\n";
    SHUFFLE(deck[size2], deckindex[size1],  used[size2],  usedindex[size2],  c2[4],  c3[4], c4[4],  c5[4],  c6[4],  c7[4],  c8[4],  c9[4],  c10[4],  c11[4],  c12[4], c13[4],  c14[4] );
    while(count<1000) count++;
    cout<<"OK!\n";
    cout<<"Distributing cards for players...\n";
    cout << "Give me a second...\n";
    HANDDISTRO( hand1[size3],  deck[size2],  hand1index[size3],  deckindex[size2],  used[size2],  hand2[size3],  hand2index[size3],  hand3[size3],  hand3index[size3],  hand4[size3],  hand4index[size3]);
    count=0;
    while(count<1000) count++;
    cout<<"OK!\n";
    cout<<"PLAYER 1 has: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
      cout<<hand1[i]<<" "<<hand1index[i]<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"PLAYER 2 has: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
      cout<<hand2[i]<<" "<<hand2index[i]<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"PLAYER 3 has: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
      cout<<hand3[i]<<" "<<hand3index[i]<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"PLAYER 4 has: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
      cout<<hand4[i]<<" "<<hand4index[i]<<"\n";
    }
    cout << "Distributing cards on deck...\n";
    int fat = 5; //fat...
    for(int i=0; i<fat; i++){
    ONDECK(Ondeck[size1], used[size2], deck[size2], i);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<fat; i++){
    ONDECKINDEX(Ondeckindex[size1], used[size2], i, deckindex[size2]);
    }
    cout << "DONE!\n";
    cout << "Cards on deck are:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
      cout<<Ondeck[i]<<" "<<Ondeckindex<<"\n";
    }
    cout << "Checking hands...\n";
    if(RoyalFlush1(hand1[size3], Ondeck[size1], RF[size1])==true){
      score1=90;
      winhand1="ROYALFLUSH";
    }
    else if(straightflush1(hand1index[2], Ondeckindex[5],hand1[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score1=80;
      winhand1="STRAIGHTFLUSH";
    }
    else if(fourofkind1(hand1[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score1=70;
      winhand1="FOUR OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(fullhouse1(hand1[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score1=60;
      winhand1="FULLHOUSE";
    }
    else if(flush1(hand1index[size3],Ondeckindex[size1])==true){
      score1=50;
      winhand1="FLUSH";
    }
    else if(Straight1(hand1[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score1=40;
      winhand1="STRAIGHT";
    }
    else if(threeofkind1(hand1[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score1=30;
      winhand1="THREE OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(twopair1(hand1[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score1=20;
      winhand1="TWO PAIR";
    }
    else if(onepair1(hand1[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score1=10;
      winhand1="ONE PAIR";
    }
    if(RoyalFlush2(hand2[size3], Ondeck[size1], RF[size1])==true){
      score2=90;
      winhand2="ROYALFLUSH";
    }
    else if(straightflush2(hand2index[2], Ondeckindex[5],hand2[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score2=80;
      winhand2="STRAIGHTFLUSH";
    }
    else if(fourofkind2(hand2[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score2=70;
      winhand2="FOUR OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(fullhouse2(hand2[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score2=60;
      winhand2="FULLHOUSE";
    }
    else if(flush2(hand2index[size3],Ondeckindex[size1])==true){
      score2=50;
      winhand2="FLUSH";
    }
    else if(Straight2(hand2[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score2=40;
      winhand2="STRAIGHT";
    }
    else if(threeofkind2(hand2[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score2=30;
      winhand2="THREE OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(twopair2(hand2[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score2=20;
      winhand2="TWO PAIR";
    }
    else if(onepair2(hand2[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score2=10;
      winhand2="ONEPAIR";
    }
    if(RoyalFlush3(hand3[size3], Ondeck[size1], RF[size1])==true){
      score3=90;
      winhand3="ROYALFLUSH";
    }
    else if(straightflush3(hand3index[2], Ondeckindex[5],hand3[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score3=80;
      winhand3="STRAIGHTFLUSH";
    }
    else if(fourofkind3(hand3[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score3=70;
      winhand3="FOUR OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(fullhouse3(hand3[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score3=60;
      winhand3="FULLHOUSE";
    }
    else if(flush3(hand3index[size3],Ondeckindex[size1])==true){
      score3=50;
      winhand3="FLUSH";
    }
    else if(Straight3(hand3[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score3=40;
      winhand3="STRAIGHT";
    }
    else if(threeofkind3(hand3[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score3=30;
      winhand3="THREE OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(twopair3(hand3[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score3=20;
      winhand3="TWO PAIR";
    }
    else if(onepair3(hand3[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score3=10;
      winhand3="ONE PAIR";
    }
    if(RoyalFlush4(hand4[size3], Ondeck[size1], RF[size1])==true){
      score4=90;
      winhand4="ROYALFLUSH";
    }
    else if(straightflush4(hand4index[2], Ondeckindex[5],hand4[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score4=80;
      winhand4="STRAIGHTFLUSH";
    }
    else if(fourofkind4(hand4[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score4=70;
      winhand4="FOUR OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(fullhouse4(hand4[2], Ondeck[5])==true){
      score4=60;
      winhand4="FULLHOUSE";
    }
    else if(flush4(hand4index[size3],Ondeckindex[size1])==true){
      score4=50;
      winhand4="FLUSH";
    }
    else if(Straight4(hand4[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score4=40;
      winhand4="STRAIGHT";
    }
    else if(threeofkind4(hand4[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score4=30;
      winhand4="THREE OF A KIND";
    }
    else if(twopair4(hand4[size3], Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score4=20;
      winhand4="TWO PAIR";
    }
    else if(onepair4(hand4[size3],Ondeck[size1])==true){
      score4=10;
      winhand4="ONE PAIR";
    }

    if(score1>score2 && score1>score3 && score1>score4){
      cout<<"Player 1 wins with a hand of "<<winhand1<<"\n";
      cout<<"CONGRATULATIONS!\n";
      EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if(score2>score1 && score2>score3 && score2>score4){
      cout<<"Player 2 wins with a hand of "<<winhand2<<"\n";
      cout<<"CONGRATULATIONS!\n";
      EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if(score3>score1 && score3>score2 && score3>score4){
      cout<<"Player 3 wins with a hand of "<<winhand3<<"\n";
      cout<<"CONGRATULATIONS!\n";
      EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if(score4>score1 && score4>score2 && score4>score1){
      cout<<"Player 4 wins with a hand of "<<winhand4<<"\n";
      cout<<"CONGRATULATIONS!\n";
      EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  }
  else {
    cout<<"WRONG INPUT!\n";
    goto label1;
  }
}
} //closing main
```

Comment: you are missing a link - but with this current text, it is hard to see. perhaps, add code.

Comment: How are you compiling this? It seems as though your linker can't find the standard C++ library file.

Comment: I am very sorry for the messy output, I don't know how to leave the original formatting.

Comment: I am compiling using g++, the command I used is: g++ -std=c++11 -o poker1Out poker1.cpp

Comment: I just asked someone and he told me the same thing i.e it's a linker error. He suggested using visual studio and turning off the linker to compile.

Comment: I tried adding code but it's over 1600 lines and the website is not allowing me.

Comment: Do you have several files ?

Comment: No the program is only 1 .cpp file

Comment: should i delete the Compiler output and put my source code instead?

Comment: Where are your symbols defined?

Comment: Post the code for `main`.   Are all the functions listed in the error messages accounted for?  Did you forget to implement some?  Are the functions in different namespaces?  Does `main` have the correct function declarations?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "symbols"

Comment: Symbols:  variable names, function names, and method names. The text `fourofakind4` is a function name.  Your linker can't find it.

Comment: They are all in the same file, functions go after main and function prototypes before it.

Comment: You compile with G++, but provide us a clang compiler output? Are you sure?

Comment: @cdonat maybe he's using a Mac. GCC is symlinked to clang on OS X (on Mavericks, at least), as far as I remember from using Hackintosh.

Comment: 100% sure i compile with g++, if i were able to post a screen shot of the terminal i would have showed you.

Comment: Yes i'm using a mac.

Comment: @user3857450 are you sure that names of your functions match in prototypes and definitions?

Comment: So, you are not compiling with g++, but with clang. Just your buggy system makes you think so.

Comment: Well if you put it that way i guess so...

Comment: As the program compiles you clearly don't provide the full code. All headers or function declarations is missing. `g++ -std=c++11 -o poker1Out poker1.cpp` wouldn't even compile with the code you provided.

Comment: I checked them and they seem to match

Comment: If you read the previous comments you would have realized that I am not able to post the whole source code since stack overflow considers it to big

Comment: I can post the entire source code instead of the compiler output

Comment: I'll add a link to pastebin to put the rest of the code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/njdAzmrB

Answer (score 1):

This is a linker error message, not a compiler error message. It tells you, that it can not find the implementation of `HANDDISTRO()`.

Those are very diferent:

```
void HANDDISTRO(int, int, string, string,
                int, int, string,
                int, string,
                int , string);
```

This expects `int`s and `string`s.

```
void HANDDISTRO(int hand1[], int deck[], string hand1index[], string deckindex[],
                int used[], int hand2[], string hand2index[],
                int hand3[], string hand3index[],
                int hand4[], string hand4index[])
```

This expects arrays of `int`s and arrays of `string`s. Of course and array of `int`s is not the same as an `int`.

Comment: Well I checked the function multiple times and it is clearly implemented in the function's scope.

Comment: Do i post the entire code instead of the compiler output?

Comment: Since I don't know anything about your code, I can't tell. Is the implementation of `HANDDISTRO()` in a different cpp file?

Comment: Thanks a lot I rewrote all of the function declarations and callings and now the program is running, things is now i need to deal with some of the run time errors :)